# In Android SDK, when trying to use Class.forName, I get a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, class, reflection, telephonymanager

I think that this question may have been asked before, but I was unable to add any comments to answers, so I am asking again.

When I use the following code, I get an error with the Class.forName line.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

**EDIT**

I have tried using the ITelephony.AIDL that I've seen mentioned... is that file supposed to be called ITelephony.java?

Per a comment here, I changed the code to the following; I now get a "NoSuchMethodException".

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = tm.getClass();
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: Um, why aren't you just using `tm.getClass()` to get the class?

Comment: @CommonsWare - When I do that, I then get a "NoSuchMethodException" on the next line.  `Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony"); `



Also, sorry for not replying sooner; I've been busy with work and haven't checked here in a while.